# Return type of 'getItem' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing a simple coupon application, but recently I updated some dependencies and my `Fragment` *doesn't* allow me to `return null`

Photo of the error:
[image: error]

[image: error2]

```
package com.szakes1.makdolannative.adapters

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.R
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.fragments.CouponFragment
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.fragments.HomeFragment

class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, private val numberOfFrags: Int) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return HomeFragment()
            1 -> return CouponFragment(R.drawable.coupon_hamburger)
            2 -> return CouponFragment(R.drawable.coupon_icecream)
            3 -> return CouponFragment(R.drawable.coupon_cheeseburger)
            4 -> return CouponFragment(R.drawable.coupon_fries)
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return numberOfFrags
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return "Jak używać?"
            1 -> return "Hamburger"
            2 -> return "Lody"
            3 -> return "Cheeseburger"
            4 -> return "Małe frytki"
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the super method is defined in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as follows:

```
@NonNull
public abstract Fragment getItem(int position);
```

So, you cannot have nullable in your overriden method:

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
```

And finally, don't return `null` from the `getItem(..)` function. Instead, throw an exception

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    when (position) {
       .....
    }
    throw IllegalStateException("position $position is invalid for this viewpager")
}
```

Comment: Can you help me do it? I'm quite new and I don't know what exception to throw.

Answer (score 2):

From your `fun getItem(position: Int)` method, inside

```
when(position) {
    //In these brackets
}
```

1. Just delete `return null`
2. Then below `4 -> return "Małe frytki"` add this line:

   ```
   else -> {throw IllegalStateException("$position is illegal") }
   ```